# Обрезать картинку в background:url

Tags: html, css, background

```
body {
    background: url(./img/body_alt.jpg) top center no-repeat fixed;
    }
```

Изображение: 1920х1080px. 
Внутри `<body>`  конечно же есть внутренние элементы. 
Как обрезать изображение до 290px высотой?

Comment: Обрежьте в фотошопе

Comment: @Abmin к сожалению, не выход. Необходимо через css

Comment: Обрезайте на стороне php или на чём там у вас бэкенд.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev через CSS это сделать нельзя, я так понимаю?

Comment: а объясните, зачем Вам её обрезать? чтобы фоном у всего боди была только какая-то часть картинки? или чтобы фон занимал только какую-то часть боди, а остальное пространство было без фона?

Comment: @humster_spb чтобы фон занимал только какую-то часть боди, а остальное пространство было без фона

Comment: Я так и не понял, что мешает вам обрезать в фотошопе

Comment: @theblackpost нет, в вашем случаи вам нужно подготовить фон. Лучше, как предлагают, через фотошоп

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно сделать часть фона, то самый просто вариант - задать фон не body, а какому-то зафиксированному блоку высотой 290px:

```css
.fon-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 290px;
  background: url('https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/58ed2c368452515b5e74b50e.jpg') top center no-repeat fixed;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 1000px;
}
.content h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.content p {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fon-wrap"></div>
<div class="content">
<h1>ЗАГОЛОВОК</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
<p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```